# superagent handle compressed json response

Tags: javascript, superagent

I have a simple superagent get request, but want to use compression for transfer, as the jsons are quite large. The response, by looking at the network log is a stream, but superagent is not decoding it. Did not find clues on google why.
Request, Response headers and code follows

[image]
[image]

```
const res = await superagent
  .get(`/liveEntries`)
  .set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .set("Accept", "application/octet-stream")
  .buffer(true)
  .parse("application/octet-stream");
```